# FooTable Bootstrap Gridview Column Width when Paging

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, paging, footable

I have most of my FooTable Gridview working.
The Expand (Plus/Minus) icons are not appearing, but the Grid is Responsive and I finally got the Paging working.

The problem I now have is that the width of the first column (a CommandField with Edit/Delete) is unexpectedly widened when Paging is active.

The Non-Paging Columns look like:

[image]

But when I implement the Paging it looks like:

[image]

Notice how the first column has grown in width such that when the screen 'real estate' is minimized (as in Phone), column #2 (Device ID) is not even visible at all without scrolling to the right.

I can readily post any code for review, but I am not sure what code to post.

Any assistance/suggestions you can provide will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was going wrong.
In the Gridview parameters it was originally set to:

```
CssClass="footable table toggle-medium"
```

Once I change it to the following the column width returned to normal:

```
CssClass="footable"
```

Thanks